# Substrate tutorials - trait `MaxEncodedLen` is not implemented for `Vec<u8>`

Tags: rust, substrate

Presently, in working through the substrate tutorials, I've got to the ["Build the runtime with your new pallet"](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/v3/proof-of-existence/#build-the-runtime-with-your-new-pallet) section. With files updated and double checked as per the tutorial.

I'm getting the following error on pre-build check (the previous tutorials had built ok, Ubuntu 20.04.3):

```
cargo check -p node-template-runtime
```

Gives:

```
cargo check -p node-template-runtime
    Updating git repository `https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git`
    Checking sp-std v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?tag=monthly-2021-11-1#352c46a6)
   Compiling node-template-runtime v4.0.0-dev (/myPath/substrate/att2/substrate-node-template/runtime)
    Checking pallet-template v4.0.0-dev (/myPath/substrate/att2/substrate-node-template/pallets/template)
error[E0277]: the trait bound `Vec<u8>: MaxEncodedLen` is not satisfied
  --> pallets/template/src/lib.rs:40:11
   |
40 | #[pallet::generate_storage_info]
   |           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `MaxEncodedLen` is not implemented for `Vec<u8>`
   |
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `StorageInfoTrait` for `frame_support::pallet_prelude::StorageMap<_GeneratedPrefixForStorageProofs<T>, frame_support::Blake2_128Concat, Vec<u8>, (<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId, <T as frame_system::Config>::BlockNumber), frame_support::pallet_prelude::ValueQuery>`
note: required by `storage_info`
  --> /myPath/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/352c46a/frame/support/src/traits/storage.rs:71:2
   |
71 |     fn storage_info() -> Vec<StorageInfo>;
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
error: could not compile `pallet-template` due to previous error
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error: build failed
```

I have the following in my `Cargo.toml`:

```
[dependencies.sp-std]
default-features = false
git = 'https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git'
tag = 'monthly-2021-11-1'  # or the latest monthly
version = '4.0.0-dev'      # or the latest version
```

Is there some obvious thing that might've gone wrong?
How might I start to debug/fix this?

Comment: @NukeManDan Thank you, I'll update the question :-)

Comment: I agree an issue to fix this if it's indeed a breaking change is in order @Stargateur - https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-docs/issues/648 /// https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/devhub/latest is upstream, so should not be an issue with breaking changes in substrate #10043

Comment: what version of the node are you using and what is the substrate git tag your are targeting @atomh33ls? You can find this in your `Cargo.toml` files

Comment: PS: https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-docs/issues/627 is what we will fix shortly to address the same problem.

Comment: much better question, as nukemandan open the issue on github, I have no further complain

Comment: happy to move to resolve on github @atomh33ls - in #627

Comment: @NukeManDan yes, thanks, the suggestion there works and could be added as an answer here (I'm unsure if it'll affect later part of the tutorial atm though).

Comment: Hi Atomh33ls, Can you please support our Substrate StackExchange proposal: https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/126136

Comment: @ShawnTabrizi I did a couple of weeks ago, so close now!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the latest [frame_support::pallet](https://crates.parity.io/frame_support/attr.pallet.html), `#[pallet::generate_storage_info]` is no longer explicitly available.
And if someone is still getting the error

> the trait MaxEncodedLen is not implemented for xxx

add `#[pallet::without_storage_info]` after `#[pallet::pallet]`

Answer (score 2):

For now, all that is needed it to remove the `#[pallet::generate_storage_info]` macro line.

Future users should not have this error.
See https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-docs/issues/627

Comment: I get this error, but I don't have the `#[pallet::generate_storage_info]` code.

Comment: @ivanceras Im getting the same , how did you resolve it ?

Comment: Update your version

Answer (score 1):

For error of `no function or associated item named "max_encoded_len" found for struct "Vec<u8>" in the current scope function or associated item not found in "Vec<u8>"`

if you have a struct like

```rust
    #[derive(Default, Encode, Decode, Clone, MaxEncodedLen, PartialEq, RuntimeDebug, TypeInfo)]
    pub struct UserInfo {
        pub id: i64,
        pub username: Vec<u8>, //bytes
    }
```

Replace `Vec<u8>` with `[u8; 256]` because Rust does not know the max length of that vector.